# Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $x\sqrt{1+y}+y\sqrt{1+x}=0$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differentials

> Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $x\sqrt{1+y}+y\sqrt{1+x}=0$ for $-1\leq x\leq 1$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}\text{ if }x\neq y$$

If it was like $y=\sqrt{1+x}$ i think i know how to do it

```
D[Sqrt[1+x],x]
```

but how do i differentiate the functions like the one above ?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps not the most optimal method, but you could:

1. Take the total derivative with respect to x
2. Solve for y'[x]
3. Solve the given equation for y
4. Substitute (3) in (2)
5. Simplify, assuming bounds for x given

   ```
   Simplify[
          Solve[Dt[x \[Sqrt](1 + y) + y \[Sqrt](1 + x), x] == 0, 
                Dt[y, x]] /. 
              y -> Solve[x \[Sqrt](1 + y) + y \[Sqrt](1 + x) == 0, y][[1, 1, 2]],
           Assumptions -> {x >= -1, x <= 1}][[1, 1, 2]]
   ```

output:

```
-(1/(1 + x)^2)
```

Edit: @Nasser gives the "more optimal" method I suggested in the beginning.  I do too much solving and differentiating.

Instead of Differentiating, Solving, Solving, Substituting, and Simplifying (5 steps); why not just Substitute, Solve, Differentiate, and Simplify (4 steps) (Nasser's improvement)?  Alternatively (my slight improvement), just Solve, Differentiate, and Simplify (3 steps):

```
Dt[Solve[x √(1 + y) + y √(1 + x) == 0, y], 
  x] // Simplify
```

Out:

```
{{Dt[y, x] -> -(1/(1 + x)^2)}}
```

Easier to look at version: 
[image: Traditional Form output]

It turns out that including the bounds on x are redundant!  However, if you wish to include them (again, unnecessary):

```
Simplify[Dt[Solve[Sqrt[x + 1] y + x Sqrt[y + 1] == 0, y], {x}], 
 Assumptions -> {x >= -1 && x <= 1}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just substitude  `y->y[x]`

**First atttempt**:

```
Solve[0 == D[x Sqrt[1 + y[x]] + y[x] Sqrt[1 + x], x], y'[x]][[1]]
(*{Derivative[1][y][x] -> (Sqrt[1 + y[x]] (y[x] + 2 Sqrt[1 + x] Sqrt[1 + y[x]]))/(Sqrt[1 + x] (-x - 2 Sqrt[1 + x] Sqrt[1 + y[x]]))} *)
```

Everything is ok but knowledge about y is not included.

**Final answer**

```
eq= x \[Sqrt](1 + y[x]) + y[x] \[Sqrt](1 + x);
sol=Solve[{eq==0,D[eq,x]==0},{y[x],y'[x]}];
Simplify[sol,-1<=x<=1][[1]];
(* {y[x] -> -(x/(1 + x)), Derivative[1][y][x] -> -(1/(1 + x)^2)} *)
```

Comment: How does that answer the OP's question?

Comment: @MaxCoplan Why not, the OP has not said that the answer should be in terms of x.

Comment: thnx. but i am trying to get the same simplified answer as i have obtained whn solved myself.

Comment: @yarchik That's better now.  OP did ask for the answer to be y'=-1/(x+1)^2, which is a function of x.  UlrichNeumann now has it in terms of x

Answer (score 3):

Why not just

```
ClearAll[y,x]
expr = x Sqrt[1+y]+y Sqrt[1+x]==0;
expr = expr/.y->y[x];
D[Solve[expr,y[x]],x]//Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am not sure if this is what the above answer is doing, but I get different output, from each so I thought to post this. If it turns out to be just a extra simplification step is needed, will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function and its implicit derivative both vanish, so that gives a system of two equations in the two variables `{y[x],y'[x]}` to solve in terms of `x`.

```
expr = x *Sqrt[1 + y] + y*Sqrt[1 + x];
eyx = expr /. y -> y[x];
Simplify[y'[x] /. First[Solve[{D[eyx, x], eyx} == 0, {y[x], y'[x]}]]]

(* Out[43]= (
4 x + 3 x^2 - 4 Sqrt[1/(1 + x)] (1 + x)^(5/2))/((1 + x)^2 (2 + x)^2) *)
```